# sql server query to retreive all constraint informations

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I have a workflow that create all table of Database1 called DB1 in another database called DB2; to do that I use the following code:

```
declare @TableName nvarchar(max)
declare @SqlQuery nvarchar(max)
DECLARE tableCursor CURSOR FOR  
    select name from wt_delivery.sys.tables where name not like '%temp%'  and name not like '%acme%'
    order by name
    OPEN tableCursor

FETCH tableCursor INTO @TableName 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0        
        BEGIN
            set @SqlQuery = N'select * into Acme.dbo.[' + @TableName + N'] from wt_delivery.dbo.[' + @TableName + N'] where 1 = 2'
            print @SqlQuery
            insert into acme..AcmeLog(Task,error) values('création de la table' + @TableName,ERROR_MESSAGE())
            EXECUTE  sp_executesql @SqlQuery                        
        FETCH tableCursor INTO @TableName           
        END          
CLOSE tableCursor
DEALLOCATE tableCursor
```

I then run another query in order to fill DB2 tables with content

The problem is the query `select * into tableX from tableY` don't copy all the constraints of tableY into tableX.

to create the Foreign key I could create a cursor and use the following query:

```
SELECT   
f.name AS foreign_key_name  

   ,OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) AS table_name  
   ,COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) AS constraint_column_name  
   ,OBJECT_NAME (f.referenced_object_id) AS referenced_object  
   ,COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) AS referenced_column_name  
   ,is_disabled  
   ,delete_referential_action_desc  
   ,update_referential_action_desc  
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS f  
INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fc   
   ON f.object_id = fc.constraint_object_id   
WHERE f.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('action');
```

Are there a way to copy all constraints from one database to another (on the same tables)?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just take a backup of Database1 and restore it as Database2? This would copy the entire thing, all data, constraints etc...

Comment: because I would filter on only one customer. And if I execute delete query to do it it take several hours

Comment: Then why not use the scripting tool to generate your ddl? Right click the database in SSMS. Then Tasks -> Generate Scripts... That is the easiest way to generate all the objects. This captures ALL of them including procs, views, functions etc that just selecting data would skip.